# How can I find an Android encryption library or class compatible with my C# code?

Tags: c#, java, android, web-services, encryption

I am using the following class for data encryption in C# .net. What is the equivalent library or algorithm in java android for transferring data between android and web-service?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Crypto
/// </summary>

public enum SymmProvEnum : int
        {
            DES, RC2, Rijndael
        }
public class Crypto
{

    string Globalkey = "test";
        private SymmetricAlgorithm mobjCryptoService;

        /// <remarks>
        /// Constructor for using an intrinsic .Net SymmetricAlgorithm class.
        /// </remarks>
        public Crypto()
        {
            //switch (NetSelected)
            //{
            //    case SymmProvEnum.DES:
            //        mobjCryptoService = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //        break;
            //    case SymmProvEnum.RC2:
            //        mobjCryptoService = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();
            //        break;
            //    case SymmProvEnum.Rijndael:
            //        mobjCryptoService = new RijndaelManaged();
            //        break;
            //}
            mobjCryptoService = new RijndaelManaged();
        }

        /// <remarks>
        /// Constructor for using a customized SymmetricAlgorithm class.
        /// </remarks>
        //public Crypto(SymmetricAlgorithm ServiceProvider)
        //{
        //    mobjCryptoService = ServiceProvider;
        //}

        /// <remarks>
        /// Depending on the legal key size limitations of a specific CryptoService provider
        /// and length of the private key provided, padding the secret key with space character
        /// to meet the legal size of the algorithm.
        /// </remarks>
        private byte[] GetLegalKey(string Key)
        {
            string key = Globalkey;
            string sTemp;
            if (mobjCryptoService.LegalKeySizes.Length > 0)
            {
                int lessSize = 0, moreSize = mobjCryptoService.LegalKeySizes[0].MinSize;
                // key sizes are in bits
                while (Key.Length * 8 > moreSize)
                {
                    lessSize = moreSize;
                    moreSize += mobjCryptoService.LegalKeySizes[0].SkipSize;
                }
                sTemp = Key.PadRight(moreSize / 8, ' ');
            }
            else
                sTemp = Key;

            // convert the secret key to byte array
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sTemp);
        }

        public string Encrypt(string Source)
        {
            string Key = Globalkey;
            byte[] bytIn = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Source);
            // create a MemoryStream so that the process can be done without I/O files
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            byte[] bytKey = GetLegalKey(Key);

            // set the private key
            mobjCryptoService.Key = bytKey;
            mobjCryptoService.IV = bytKey;

            // create an Encryptor from the Provider Service instance
            ICryptoTransform encrypto = mobjCryptoService.CreateEncryptor();

            // create Crypto Stream that transforms a stream using the encryption
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypto, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // write out encrypted content into MemoryStream
            cs.Write(bytIn, 0, bytIn.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            // get the output and trim the '\0' bytes
            byte[] bytOut = ms.GetBuffer();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < bytOut.Length; i++)
                if (bytOut[i] == 0)
                    break;

            // convert into Base64 so that the result can be used in xml
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytOut, 0, i);
        }

        public string Decrypt(string Source)
        {
            string Key = Globalkey;
            // convert from Base64 to binary
            byte[] bytIn = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Source);
            // create a MemoryStream with the input
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytIn, 0, bytIn.Length);

            byte[] bytKey = GetLegalKey(Key);

            // set the private key
            mobjCryptoService.Key = bytKey;
            mobjCryptoService.IV = bytKey;

            // create a Decryptor from the Provider Service instance
            ICryptoTransform encrypto = mobjCryptoService.CreateDecryptor();

            // create Crypto Stream that transforms a stream using the decryption
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypto, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            // read out the result from the Crypto Stream
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader( cs );
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
}
```

Comment: First of all what you want to do in Android? Encryption or Decryption? I used bountycastle library. It will 99.99% support what you are asking for.  To make the library lesser size just remove cryptographic classes alone from that and include in your jar.

Comment: Is it possible to replace your C# code? It contains a number of severe flaws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a crypto class that should work with your code, given correct configuration.

You can check it out here: https://github.com/Untouchab1e/yubinotes/blob/master/Android/src/com/connectutb/yubinotes/util/Crypto.java

You're using DES in your example, which is a flawed and obsolete algorithm (alternatively use 3DES), so I suggest moving to AES which provides better encryption.

Comment: what is `iv` in `Crypto(String iv, String SecretKey)`?

Comment: `iv` is initialization vector.  It should be the same value that you used for encryption.

Comment: i my example there is no `String iv` as input

Comment: @Satish In my c# example there is no `String iv` as input.

Comment: byte[] bytKey = GetLegalKey(Key);
mobjCryptoService.IV = bytKey;
I see you are doing these?

Comment: @Satish My problem is that I can not implement method `GetLegalKey()` in Android. How can I do that?

Comment: First of all do you want to do both encryption and decryption in android? iv can be any random value but the only condition is both encryption and decryption should use the same value. You can also use 0/NULL for that but avoid doing that. You can keep it 0/NULL for testing.  Just do byte iv[] = new byte[16];  This will randomly fill iv.

Comment: @Satish The C# code is what is happening in my Web service and I can not change the web service. So I have to implement exactly what is happening in C# code in my Android code.

Comment: Are you encrypting in android and decrypting in c# webservice or other way around?

Comment: @Satish Yes I am encrypting in android and decrypting in c# webservice and I can not change the web service

Comment: @Satish the problem is I do not know what is `MinSize`, `SkipSize` and `mobjCryptoService.LegalKeySizes.Length` in method `GetLegalKey(...)` for Android

Comment: Then you have to implement GetLegalKey() in your android.  You have to understand by debugging what it does in C# and implement in android.  No shortcut because iv has to be same.

Comment: GlobalKey is "test".  I hope this won't change.  He seems to be padding the key with ' '(space) depending on iv size.  What you do is after calling GetLegalKey() convert it to string and see how many he has padded with ' '(space).  Pad the same in android.  This is good as long as Algorithm and GlobalKey does not change.

Comment: thanks! I customized your sample and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

AES is supported by Android & C#.

Here's an encryption example using AES:

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clearTextBytes);
```

Here's some more documentation on the Android Cipher class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I get error `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.`

Comment: yea, ensure your keyBytes have exactly 16 / 24 / 32 bytes. You can pad with 0 bytes if your key bytes are shorter.

Comment: AES has nothing to do with DES. You appear to be confusing AES with Triple DES.

Comment: oh crap, you're absolutely right... editing! sorry, it's a bit late here... :/